# Prevent Microsoft teams from automatically changing status to “away” after inactivity

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, microsoft

Teams always sets your status to "away" after some amount of time of inactivity in the app. It's really annoying. I don't want to buy a "mouse jiggler" just for this, and I can't install anything or write any automation scripts on my work machine.

I still want it to go red when I have outlook meetings, but other than that I want it to always say available. What can I do?

Comment: Looking to get fired then?

Comment: [Set a duration for your status in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-duration-for-your-status-in-teams-d82c5629-96a8-44e9-bced-2925470e0d96) ?

Answer (score -2):

Here’s what you do:

1. Make a teams call to someone. If you can find an old teams meeting room that nobody is using anymore, that will work.
2. Stay on the teams call all day. Your status will show “in a call”
3. Manually change status to “Available”

Now your teams status will stay as “Available”, it will still change during an outlook meeting automatically, but it will never automatically change to “Away” as long as you stay in the call. This will also prevent your computer from sleeping.